# facebook crawl wrong final url

Tags: facebook-like, web-crawler

I use facebook debug og to see what facebook crawled..

```
Final URL:  http://xxx.appspot.com/?_escaped_fragment_=homePage
Canonical URL:  http://xxx.appspot.com/#!homePage
```

The canonical url is correctly crawled by facebook. but why the final url is wrong? when user pressed the like button. i pass in href=http://xxx.appspot.com/#!homePage   . Aren't final url should look the same like canonical url?

my page is at http://tinyurl.com/7luzm68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the #! in the url. By using that, you are opting into using the [ajax crawling spec](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/specification.html), thus giving you the `_escaped_fragment_` part. The reason this is done is because the fragment (everything after the #) isn't sent to the request, so there is no way for the server to know that you're trying to load `homePage`, for example.

Comment: it is sent as request because i encoded the url before pass to facebook like href http%3A%2F%2F1.xxx.appspot.com%2F%23!homePage  ..   the reason final url should not have _escaped_fragment is because, when the link is showing up on the facebook wall, the link will have _escaped_fragment...

Comment: does it mean by using ajax crawl spec, i cannot link to particular page after #, rather can only link to http://xxx.appspot.com/

Comment: The link on people's wall should be normal. Only when the url is crawled by Facebook (and Google) will it be converted to _escaped_fragment_. The crawler does not have JS capabilities, so you can use this to place the proper open graph tags in the head element.

Comment: sorry i dont get it. can you explain whether can use  xxx.appspot.com/#!pageX ? i still dont get it why when i view the wall post, it has _escaped_fragment . what i trying to say is, user that click on this wall post will link to non-js version of the page

Comment: The user will never see that link. That is only for Facebook's bot that gathers the open graph meta tags. The user will see the link with the #! but not the _escaped_fragment_